# Discord JS - Create thread from user message without ping them

Tags: discord.js

I have a bot and I want to automatically create a thread on user message.
Code bellow work:

```js
message.startThread({
    name: 'Discuss about this message in the thread bellow',
    autoArchiveDuration: 60,
});
```

My problem is that this thread is considered as a reply of user message, and so ping them :

[image: The message]
[image: The unwanted ping]

Is there a way to not ping the user in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot create a thread from a message without mentioning the user.

A work-around this would be to make your bot send a message with the same content, and then create a thread from the bot's message.

Another work-around, if you don't care about having a `startMessage`, is creating a thread in the channel with `message.content` as the name:

```
await message.channel.threads.create({
  name: `${message.content}`,
  autoArchiveDuration: 60,
});
```

Note that not having a `startMessage` will create an empty thread.

Comment: Thanks.
I already tried with a separate thread but I don't really like it.
I'm going to test the new message trick, thanks.